# How to use Ctrl+Space to switch between input methods on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to switch between input methods, as I have used on Windows 7 and even older versions of Windows.

With Windows 8, the default key combo is <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, for some unknown reasons.

When I looked into the settings, I see

[image: Change_Key_Sequence]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> doesn't seems to be an option anymore.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> First, press Win + W to bring up Setting Search charm and type in
>   “language”, and choose Language to open Language window.
>
> Click Add a language in Change your language preferences settings.
>
> Find your language from the long list, in this case, it’s Chinese
>   (Simplified). And double click to add it. Once it’s done, the Language
>   window looks something like this.
>
> Now click Option to change input settings. For the input I choose,
>   Pinyin SimpleFast, there are a lot of options for me to check and
>   change. I especially like the UI customization where I can change the
>   font to make my input experience much enjoyable.
>
> Now, save the change, go back to Language window. It’s time to set up
>   the hot keys to make the switching input methods much easier. Go to
>   Advanced Settings, and click Change language bar hot keys.
>
> Highlight the input method from the list, and click Change Key
>   Sequence button. I like to use Ctrl+Shift+0 to switch from English to
>   Chinese input.

[Source](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2012/08/how-to-add-chinese-input-method-in-windows-8/)

Answer (score 5):

You can use autohotkey to map ctrl+space to win+space

http://www.autohotkey.com/

^space::#space

Answer (score 2):

You can use Win+Space combination.

Comment: Thanks. This works in a similar fashion. However, do you know if there is a way to just make CTRL+SPACE work again?